# Koala не создает скомпилированный CSS-файл

Tags: less

Установил Koala, выбрал путь к папке с файлом less, рядом с ним должен был создаться скомпилированный CSS-файл, но его нет. Пробовал скомпилировать принудительно, нажав на кнопку - не помогло. 
Как возможная причина, я установил Коалу на другой диск (не тот, что предлагает по умолчанию), но переустановка не спасла. Возможно какие то файлы  в кэше остались от первой установки ?
Подскажите, кто сталкивался, пожалуйста. [image: koala]

[image: Папка с файлом]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> рядом с ним должен был создаться скомпилированный CSS-файл

С чего вы это взяли? Если у вас выходной путь указан как `..\..\css\css\styles.css`

Ищите ваш файл в папке `C:\Пользователи\Влад\Документы\html\css\css\styles.css`

Comment: Все верно. Спасибо